# Eeeeek, what happened to my edit link.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

Well, I was about to improve one of Rory's answer but can't.

Then I realised I'm not able to edit any question or answer in the security meta. Why?
It's seems to be security.se specific since the link appears in meta.gaming.se

Is it specific to me? (Or non-moderators?)

---

[image: The problem]

Comment: Oh - superb use of hand drawn circles!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot suggest edits on a meta, for the reasons outlined at the below link:

See: [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371)

Comment: Hum... is it recent? I've checked it was ok yesterday on meta.gaming and today I can't edit any-more. Well. Anyway, thanks for the link!